# Redirecting 301 from SubDomain to SubFolder / with diffrent URLs using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, cpanel

i have a web with this address(subdomain): `subd.example.com` and want to redirect it to (subfolder): `https://www.example.com/subf/`

is I searched the code bellow works if the urls in my websites wont change:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subd\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/subf/$1/ [R=301]
```

but some or most of my URLs will be changed for example from /oldlink1 to /newlink1 and ...

somehow im stuck and the codes wont work, only home page redirects correctly, i tried:

```
Redirect 301 /oldlink1 www.example.com/subf/newlink1
```

but it doesnt work, returns me this link: `www.example.com/subf/oldlink`

any help please?

**EDIT:**
if it is important both subdomain and subfolder names are the same,
I mean **subd** and **subf** are both `sub`.
addresses are:

```
sub.example.com
www.example.com/sub/
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue most likely is the position of those specific redirection rules. This is important, you need to consider that the rule set is processed top to bottom. So you need to implement specific exceptions first, so further up, and more general rules later, so further down.

This probably is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subd\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ https://example.com/subf [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subd\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?oldlink1/?$ https://example.com/subf/newlink1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subd\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?oldlink2/?$ https://example.com/subf/newlink2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subd\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?oldlink3/?$ https://example.com/subf/newlink3 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subd\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)/?$ https://example.com/subf/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: thank you for answering, but your codes didnt work too.

Comment: "Didn't work" has never helped anyone anywhere to solve any issue. You need to be specific. What does "didn't work" actually mean? What requests did you try, what results did you get? What do you see in your http server's error log file? What does your browsers networking tab in the dev console show? And what result do you actually see?

Comment: yp, i mean the result was same as what i tried in the topic i mentioned.. the address was returned this way: `www.example.com/sub/oldlink1`

Comment: That means that you are either looking at a cached result ( _you did test using a fresh anonymous browser window, I hope?_ ) or you have another redirection rule in place. That is why I asked all the questions. Not for fun, but because that is how one finds the solution. Can you answer those questions?

Comment: Do you need help answering those questions?